# What's the 'axes' field in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What's the field `axes` in the last line of the following code?

```
function drawBox2D(h,object)

% draw regular objects
if ~strcmp(object.type,'DontCare')

  rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor',occ_col{object.occlusion+1},...
            'LineWidth',3,'LineStyle',trun_style{trc},'parent',h(1).axes)
  rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','b', 'parent', h(1).axes)
```

See the `h(1).axes` in the last line? I don't know what is the `h`, don't know what to pass to that function. 
I speculate it to be a graph handle. So I tried 
h = figure(2);
drawBox2D(h, obj);

However the handle itself is an integer so there's no field called 'axes'.

Could anyone tell me who does the field `axes` belong to? And what should I pass as h into this function?

Comment: It is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3938348/1018966

Comment: Whomever wrote that function, wants the first input to be a structure with a subfield called axes. So, you need to do smt like `s.axes = gca`, and then call `drawBox2D(s,...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all *axes handles* anywhere in `Matlab`, you can do the following things:

```
allAxes = findall(0,'type','axes');
```

To select only *axes handles* not *legends*, you need to cleanup the list of `axes`

```
axNoLegendsOrColorbars= ax(~ismember(get(ax,'Tag'),{'legend','Colobar'}));
```