# Individual line and axes styles with plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

I tried creating a plot with two YAxis like this:

```
x=linspace(0,20);
y1=linspace(10,10);
y2=x.^2;
y3=y2-y1;
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2]=plotyy([x',x'],[y1',y2'],x,y3);
```

Now i have two problem with this code:

1. I can change the Linestyles of the two hLines using `hLine1.LineStyle = ':';` for example, but i can not change the styles of the two lines, that hLine1 consists of. Does anyone know how to do this?
2. I can't use `hLine2.YLim = [0 100]` to manually adjust the y-limits shown on the 2nd y-axis.

After I couldn't solve the problem using the `plotyy`, I searched the MATLAB documentation and found another way of implementing my plot, which I thought might be easier to handle:

```
x=linspace(0,20);
y1=linspace(10,10);
y2=x.^2;
y3=y2-y1;

figure
hold on;
line(x,y1,'Color','r')
line(x,y2,'Color','y')
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'YAxisLocation','right');
line(x,y3,'Parent',ax2,'Color','b')
```

The problem here is, that it doesn't even show the first and the second line, but only the third and i don't know why. I would prefer getting the problem solved using the `plotyy`, but if that's not possible I would appreciate a solution for the 2nd piece of code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't noticed that the outputs of `plotyy` are arrays of objects, and not single objects.

```
x=linspace(0,20);
y1=linspace(10,10);
y2=x.^2;
y3=y2-y1;

[hAx,hLine1,hLine2]=plotyy([x',x'],[y1',y2'],x,y3);
hLine1(1).LineStyle = '--';
hLine1(2).LineStyle = ':';

% either this
ylim( hAx(2), [0 110] );

% or alternatively
f=gcf; ylim( f.Children(2), [0 110] );
```

Comment: Thank you and you are right, i didn't notice that, thus i could've imagined since matlab actually has arrays EVERYWHERE.... But the ylim thing doesn't work, matlab tells me "Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes'." for that `ylim()` line.

Comment: @Max This is curious, what version of Matlab are you using? Alternatively, you could get the handle for each axes manually (see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938348/matlab-how-to-obtain-all-the-axes-handles-in-a-figure-handle).

Comment: @john i'm using Matlab R2015a. i will try your suggested alternative later this day, give feedback and probably accept your answer then! Thank you once again :)

Comment: ok, the alternative works, but it doesn't do, what i wanted. i wanted to change the limits of the 2nd y-axis, how do i do that now? using f.children(3) does not work.

Comment: and apart from that, i have another question which has to do with this question, but after all is not the same. Should i edit my question anyway, or ask a new question?

Comment: @Max `hAx` is a 1x2 array of axes objects. Adjust the limits using `xlim(hAx(2), newlimits)`, `hAx(2).XLim = newlimits;`, or `set(hAx(2).XLim, newlimits);`

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the first two lines because axes backgrounds are white by default. Setting the `Color` property of the second axes object to `'none'` should give you what you're looking for:

```
x=linspace(0,20);
y1=linspace(10,10);
y2=x.^2;
y3=y2-y1;

figure
hold on;
line(x,y1,'Color','r')
line(x,y2,'Color','y')
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'YAxisLocation','right', 'Color', 'none');
line(x,y3,'Parent',ax2,'Color','b')
```

[image: the plot]

EDIT: I'd also recommend checking out [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) if you're going to be zooming/panning your axes and want to keep some or all of the axes synchronized.

Comment: yes, this worked, but i'm still trying to go with the `plotyy`-solution provided by sh3ljohn. but what do you mean by "checking out" the linkaxes? like `linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'off');`?

Comment: When you use `plotyy` it links your x-axes for you, so if you zoom or pan your plots it will update the limits of both axes. Utilizing the 2-axis object solution doesn't do this so if it's behavior you want then you'll need to set it yourself.